How to read execution log in @AfterSuite in Katalon Studio for report custom formatting purpose
I try to create custom formatting report in katalon studio. I've tried with create 2 suites test run, first suite to collect test case and second suite to read first suite execution then run them use test suites collection, so far this approach success to read JUnit_Report.xml formed in the first suite via @AfterSuite in the second suite.
- first suite
  - test case 1
  - test case 2
  - etc
- second suite
  - test case fake

- test suites collection
  - first suite
  - second suite


But I think this way is not ideal, mostly other framework one of example like TestNG have an EmailableReporter class that can be leveraged.
I believe the Katalon JUnit_Report.xml report and other reports like the below image are generated through reading the execution log:

I read documentation about Katalon ReportUtil, how to use this to extract information to get summary execution like suite name, test case name, log each test case, total test and etc in @AfterSuite ? Is possible or is there another approach to read log execution for this purpose ?
